# VF: Pass inputfield back to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to pass an inputfield back to the controller.

NOTE: Do not treat "HBS ID" as a value representing a Salesforce ID. This value is similar to an employee ID you have at work.

Goal: give user ability to select Employee__c object record. This lookup value is stored in Employee__c field on Employee_Session__c.

Page section:

```
 <apex:form >
    <div id="section">
        <apex:pageblock tabStyle="Employee_Session__c" title="Merger Details">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Current HBS ID:" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
                <apex:outputLabel value="New HBS ID:" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
                <apex:outputLabel value="{!empName}" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
                <apex:inputField label="HBS ID:" id="pickerHBSID" value="{!emp.Id}" required="true" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!mergeRecords}" title="Save" value="Save">
                </apex:commandButton>                
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Controller Code:

```
 public class EmpMerge_Controller {

    list<Employee_Session__c> esList = new list<Employee_Session__c>();
    list<Task> eTasks = new list<Task>();
    public Id empId {get; set;}
    public String empName {get; set;}
    public Employees__c emp {get;set;}

    public EmpMerge_Controller() {
        //empId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
        empId = 'a00f0000006xeI6';
        //empName = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('Name');
        empName = 'TRE1';

        emp = new Employees__c();
    }

    public List<Employee_Session__c> getEmpSessions() {
        esList = [Select Id,Name,Employee__r.Name,Specialist__c,CreatedDate,LastModifiedDate 
                  FROM Employee_Session__c 
                  WHERE Employee__c = :empId];

        return esList;
    }

    public list<Task> getTasks(){
        eTasks = [Select Id,Subject,CreatedDate FROM Task WHERE WhatId = :empId];
        return eTasks;
    }

    public PageReference mergeRecords(){
        system.debug('empName = ' + emp.Name);
        system.debug('empId = ' + emp.ID);

        for(Employee_Session__c es:esList){
            es.Employee__c = emp.Id;
        }
        for(Task t:eTasks){
            t.WhatId = emp.Id;
        }
        update eTasks;
        update esList;

        return null;
    }
}
```

What it looks like: (not getting a box where i can pick the new Employee__c record). I have tried emp.Name which gives me white box but I don't get the search popup option.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SObject field such as `Employee_Session__c.Employee__c` is automatically passed back to the server and set in the field on the controller.

But for that to work in your case you need the `empSession` property to be set to an instance of `Employee_Session__c` either queried from the database if you want to edit the value or just a `empSession = new Employee_Session__c();` set in e.g. the constructor if this is purely data entry with no pre-existing value. Probably the former in your case so add this to the constructor:

```
empSession = getEmpSessions().get(0);
```

and:

```
public PageReference mergeRecords() {
    update empSession;
    return null;
}
```

**PS**

To get a lookup field rendered (a text field for the name, a hidden field for the ID and a button to display a search pop-up) you need to use a `Lookup` field not an `ID` field or a `Name` field. This is just a design chose Salesforce made.

Comment: Actually I am doing the latter. I need to capture the new ID so I can use it for updating multiple object records that all lookup to Employee.

Comment: I have updated my original post with updated controller and page. I also updated most of the description text to describe current problem.

Comment: @MattM See my PS; think your original code was a bit closer.

Comment: Lol, ok I just figured it out. Yes Keith my original code was closer.